# Select numbers not present in multiple number series in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle 10g, how do I select values which do not fit between multiple ranges. For example:

Given the numbers:

**5,
10,
20,
26,
40,
50,
55,
60,
100,
200,
203,
211,
230**

And the ranges:

**10 - 25**

**50 - 55**

**200 - 210**

The following numbers do not fit in the ranges:

**5
26
40
60
100
211
230**

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE myseries (start_sequence NUMBER(6), end_sequence NUMBER(6));

CREATE TABLE myvalues (sequence_number NUMBER(6));

INSERT INTO myseries VALUES(10,25);

INSERT INTO myseries VALUES(50,55);

INSERT INTO myseries VALUES(200,210);

-- Insert test data
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(20);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(26);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(40);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(50);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(55);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(60);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(100);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(200);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(203);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(211);
INSERT INTO myvalues VALUES(230);

select sequence_number from myvalues
where sequence_number not in (??)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select sequence_number from myvalues m
where not exists
 ( select 1 from myseries s where m.sequence_number between s.start_sequence
   and s.end_sequence )
```